# Command with variable length of parameters from file

Tags: bash

I have written a `program.sh` script that uses `$@`  to process a variable length of parameters. For instance, `./program.sh param1 param2 param3` works fine and processes all three parameters.

Then, I have a file params.txt with a variable length of parameters such that `cat params.txt` returns `param1 param2 param3 ... paramN`. The question is, how can I run `program.sh` with the parameters as given in params.txt?

For instance, I tried `cat params.txt  | ./program.sh` and `./program.sh < params.txt` without any results. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following command run the script on the given parameters:

```
./program.sh `cat params.txt`
```

Comment: This would work as long as none of the parameters contain embedded whitespace or filename globbing characters.